# pyspark count and collect method

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

when I am using count() or collect() method while writing a simple pyspark program, it gives weird error.

```
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling z:org.apache.spark.api.python.PythonRDD.collectAndServe.
```

When I am using REPL, it works without any issues which is strange.

I am new to pyspark started learning just now but researched this error extensively on internet could not resolve it.

Many mentioned it is related to spark 2.4 so i re-installed spark 2.3 but did not fixed it.

Many mentioned it is related to JDK 9 and above with spark so I installed JDK 8 but did not fixed the error.

Simple code I am writing -->

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext

sc = SparkContext("local")
print(sc.textFile("X:\\Study\Learning\Spark\Data\Test.txt").count())
```

I am using pycharm to execute the pyspark code.

I really appreciate your help if you could help me resolve this issue once. This is really frustrating.

Comment: first of all, you need to add py4j library in pycharm to make it running spark code with python.
Secondly, you also need to create spark session and spark context in order to execute the code. let me know if you still face any issue. here is the link 
https://medium.com/parrot-prediction/integrating-apache-spark-2-0-with-pycharm-ce-522a6784886f

Comment: py4j library is already added in pycharm along with other zip files. I do not understand why we need spark session? even in the example you share, is there any spark session created? (unless i am mistaken).

Comment: just to give more perspective if i replace function count with say take(), code works fine.

Comment: I think there is only configuration error otherwise it is fine.

Comment: Anyone else if you know please can you shade some light here